# How to secure session variable in HttpSession using java servlets

Tags: java, session, servlets, web

I think there should a way to set session variable with defined scope in pure java Servlet without using other library like jsf or springframework so that visibility of session variable can be restricted.

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    String userId = (String)request.getAttribute("userId");
    session.setAttribute("userId", userId);
}
```

I found ServletContext

```
ServletContext context = request.getSession().getServletContext();
context.setAttribute("userId", userId);
```

but this one doesnot seem to provide session scope flexibility.

Comment: What do you mean "restricted", and why put it in the Session in the first place?

Comment: I am actually developing liferay portlets and i am also using delegate servlet which is HttpServlet. There is function to limit scope of session variable in PortletSession but i don't find such methods to limit session variable in HttpSession.I am curious.

Answer (score 1):

You've found it. Set a session attribute. The scope of a session attribute is the scope of a session, which is a single user.

The portlet scope just controls whether the attribute is confined to the current portlet or is visible to all portlets. It's still within the user session. If you need to implement *that* feature, just bind a `Map` into the session under the name of the portlet, and have each portlet look in its own `Map.`

If you set a context attribute it will be visible to all users.

Comment: can you provide some examples or links. I would like to understand how session scope works.

Comment: It's irrelevant how it works. It belongs to a specific user. That's all you need to know. It's guaranteed by the Servlet Specification #7.

Comment: currently i am not able to uniformly share session variable from servlet.Some session variables simply just persist in hook and other portlets. Some session variable requires use of LIFERAY_SHARED_ prefix  to share with some portlets.

Comment: What exactly does 'unable' mean?

Comment: i don't understand bind a map into the session under the name of the portlet request.getSession().setAttribute("nameofPortlet",someMap);

Comment: How is that map scope is restricted to portlet scope. It  should be still in session scope.